# Java XML Reader not works for multiple elements from URL

Tags: java, arrays, xml, xmlreader

I'm using an existing XMLReader code in my project for taking elements from an XML page. It works fine for only one element like this:

```
    public String getURL(String Url) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(Url);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line;

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("presentationURL")) {
                line = line.split("<presentationURL>")[1].split("</presentationURL>")[0];
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
```

...
But when I try to add a second element right after here:

```
if(line.contains("presentationURL")) {
line = line.split("<presentationURL>")[1].split("</presentationURL>")[0];
sb.append(line);
sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

like this:

```
if(line.contains("manufacturer")) {
line = line.split("<manufacturer>")[1].split("manufacturer")[0];
sb.append(line);
sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

the program gives me Array Index Out of Bounds Exception and some other errors. How can I make this program work for more elemets?

Comment: Do *not* to use `String.split` or other low-level string operations to read XML,
because it leads to restrictions and errors (as you now already noticed).
Instead, use an [XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722140/how-can-i-parse-xml-using-java).

Comment: Do you need collect all tags or any of you know? You can see, how do it with XMLStreamReader https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836506/how-to-get-prensentationurl-from-xml-page-with-java/51858738#51858738

Comment: Can I use XML parser for urls? @ThomasFritsch

Comment: @firestarter yes, i think so. As far as i remember you can read XML from URL, InputStream, File, Reader, ...

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasFritsch , Use stax pai to read xml from an inputstream . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652299/read-xml-string-using-stax